# Slow internet due to traffic?

Tags: wireless-networking

My internet is slow, usually at night. Does that mean strangers are using my personal wifi, or are our internet resources shared within a building so to speak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a number of things, from people using your connection, to heavy congestion on WIF to ISP/provider oversubscribing.

There are some tsts you can do to start narrowing down the possibilities-

1. Connect to your router using an Ethernet cable. If this increases speed the problem is with WIFI congestion.
2. If (1) above dies not fix things, try disconnecting all lan and WIFI ports other then the one you are using. If this fixed the problem then it's congestion. of other wired users.
3. Download and run WinMTR (girl example to 8.8.8.8 or your favourite slow site) and pist result here for analysis. This won't definitively answer anything, but is likely to give hints about where the bottleneck is.